# Godot - Quaternion slerp is altering initial rotation of an object

Tags: rotation, quaternion, godot, lerp

I have a player that shoots a rocket. If the rocket has a target, I use a quaternion slerp to make it home in on that target. Free firing the rocket goes directly forwards as expected. Setting a `tracking_speed` of 1 homes directly towards the target as expected. But for some reason if I set `tracking_speed` to less than 1, the rocket's initial direction becomes (0 0, 1) no matter where the ship is pointing and then proceeds to rotate towards the target. Code below.

```
var transformed_rotation:Transform = global_transform.looking_at(target.global_transform.origin, Vector3.UP)
var new_rotation:Quat = Quat(global_transform.basis).slerp(transformed_rotation.basis, tracking_speed)

set_global_transform(Transform(new_rotation, global_transform.origin))
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue was that in `Quat(global_transform.basis)` the basis was not normalized first.